# What should we do if we noticed someone having the multiple-account problem?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

This is another take to [the problem that a new user asks a question without registering and loses the cookie](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268/should-we-encourage-a-new-user-to-register-before-he-she-asks-a-question).  In the discussion I linked to, I wanted to prevent this situation from happening, but I became unsure that it was at all possible to prevent it.  Therefore, I would like to know what should be done when this happens.

To take a concrete example, I realized that in [this question](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1785/definition-of-a-monotone-machine), the asker replied to a comment by posting an *answer*, which is a typical symptom of multiple accounts.  I quickly verified that although the asker and the user who replied had the same user name and the same icon, they were different accounts.

What should I do in a case like this?

- Flag it for a moderator attention by myself explaining the situation.
- Ask the user to do this.
- Ask the user to open a thread on meta.
- Something else.

Also, should I ask the user to register?

Note:

- I cannot verify that the two accounts really belong to the same person.
- It seems that only moderators can merge two accounts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've been poking around on meta.SO and it's fairly common for a user to request a merge, after which point a moderator deals with the problem.

I'd much rather have the user request a merge, rather than a third party, just so that everything is on the up and up. You can encourage the user to request a merge by flagging their post for moderator attention with a note explaining the problem. Or they can open a thread on meta, which might be easier because they'd have more real estate to explain the situation.

Comment: Thanks.  I added an [FAQ entry](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/424#424) whose link is intended to be given to a new user having the multiple-account problem.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: We could make a meta thread "Request username merges here" which explains the process and the benefits of merging. Then you just have to link users to that thread instead of explaining things.

Comment: @Robin: Thanks for the comment.  I had created the [FAQ entry](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/225/official-faq-for-theoretical-computer-science/424#424) exactly for that purpose.  I would like to just give a link to it as a comment and be done.  I do not mind whether it is flagging or meta thread, as long as the method is convenient for moderators.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi: I see. I hadn't seen that. I guess we can let the moderators decide whether they prefer a common thread or flagging.

Comment: I realized that a user needs [15 rep points to flag a post](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/flag-posts) and [5 rep points to post on meta](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/privileges/participate-in-meta).  This means that if a user needs some rep points before doing either of them.

Comment: [Recent example](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/suggested-edits/559).  (But I cannot guarantee that this is not a fraud.)